# element padding top/bottom as percentage of current height

Tags: css

I am trying to make a full wide element for multiple uses and I am using an svg as a background graphic. I will use it to nest things like headings, forms or anything really.

The idea is that the graphic will always stay 100% wide edge to edge of the screen, repeating horizontally and scaling when its content forces the element to expand in hight.

Got it figured out this far but heres the problem: The graphic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYHK8.jpg) has uneven top and bottom edges. What I want is to make sure that content of the element does not end up on the outside of the fill. I thought I would just set the element padding top/bottom to 20% and call it a day but it simply does not work as I was hoping it to.

I want this "padding" to be constant 20% of total element height, no matter how high or wide it is.

```
.fullwidth {
width:100%;
background-image: url(graphic.svg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-size: auto 100%;
padding:20% 0;
}

.content {
...
}
```

The result is that there is a padding but it is not constant. Instead it varies with the width of the screen. I have tried all sorts of things to make it work but I am simply unable to figure it out on my own.